# Accessing the insert statement which triggers a trigger inside the trigger's body

Tags: oracle

I have some table and I have enabled auditing on this table. Currently, I am collecting the data about who has inserted records and at what time. Now I also want to log what was the exact query he/she used to insert the record. I created a trigger which at present only logs the user and date to audit data collection table. This is code to the trigger:

```
create or replace trigger auditer
after insert on user01.sometab
for each row
insert into sys.auditlogs values(user,sysdate)
```

How can I use the same trigger to access the insert statement and insert that statement into the audit table? Is it even possible?

Comment: `SYS` is a special internal account, you should never issue DDL or DML against its objects.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Unless you want to purge the audit trail with `truncate sys.aud$` or `delete sys.fga_log$` ;-)

Comment: @YasirArsanukaev Nice try, but there is the [`DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_audit_mgmt.htm#BABJECFB) package. I'm pretty sure there is a package/command to manipulate every `sys` objects you need to modify :)

Comment: @Vincent jeez, you've just severely reduced my natural destructive potential!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can meet all your requirements with [Standard Database Auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/auditing.htm#BCGEHDAG) or with [Fine-Grained Auditing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/auditing.htm#CEGBAFIA).

For the standard auditing to also capture the SQL statements, you would set [`AUDIT_TRAIL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams017.htm#REFRN10006) initialization parameter to `DB,EXTENDED` or `XML,EXTENDED` (See ["Settings for the `AUDIT_TRAIL` Initialization Parameter"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/auditing.htm#BCGEJACG) in Database Security Guide). The audit records would include timestamps and SQL text, and could be queried from `SYS.AUD$` table if `AUDIT_TRAIL` value is set to `DB,EXTENDED` or `DB`, or read from OS files if `AUDIT_TRAIL` is set to `XML,EXTENDED` or `XML`. In the latter case you can determine where the audit files are located based on the value of the initialization parameter [`AUDIT_FILE_DEST`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams014.htm#REFRN10004):

```
SQL> show parameter audit

NAME                 TYPE        VALUE
-------------------- ----------- ------------------------------
audit_file_dest      string      /u01/app/oracle/admin/orcl/adump
```

As far as FGA is concerned, I have already described it in [my other post here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40420/119). You would just need to set the other value for the `audit_trail` parameter when creating the FGA with `DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY` procedure, e. g. `DBMS_FGA.DB_EXTENDED`.